# SQLAlchemy one to many relationship, how to filter the collection

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

Bacially `Product` has a one to many relationship to `ProductPicture`.

My product picture model looks like this:

```py
PictureTypes = Literal['main', 'related', 'option']

class ProductPicture(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product_pictures'

    picture_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('products.product_id'))
    picture_type: Mapped[PictureTypes] = mapped_column(Enum(*get_args(PictureTypes)))
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120))
```

and my product model looks like this:

```py
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    product_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    product_pictures: Mapped[List["ProductPicture"]] = relationship()
```

My question is for one product I might have different types of product pictures. I know if I have a `Product` instance `p`, I can call `p.product_pictures` to get all types of product pictures. However, I want something like `p.main_pictures` which get all the product pictures of type `'main'`, and `p.option_pictures` gets all the product pictures of type `'option'`. Is there a good way to do it?

---

<sub>This question has been updated for SQLAlchemy 2.0 to reflect the [2.0 style](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/glossary.html#term-2.0-style) while maintaining the original intent as of [this prior revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24947160/2) which was written in the 1.x style.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This answer has been updated for SQLAlchemy 2.0 to reflect the [2.0 style](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/glossary.html#term-2.0-style) while maintaining the original intent of [this prior revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24947583/2) which was written in the 1.x style.</sub>

---

Referencing the documentation for relationships, we may find that under the later portion of section [late-evaluation of relationship arguments](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#late-evaluation-of-relationship-arguments), that it is possible to limit what's being included by explicitly define the condition using the [`primaryjoin`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) argument.  Adapting the documented examples to your requirements, the `Product` class may now be defined follows:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    product_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    product_pictures: Mapped[List["ProductPicture"]] = relationship()
    main_pictures: Mapped[List["ProductPicture"]] = relationship(
        viewonly=True,
        primaryjoin=lambda: and_(
            Product.product_id == ProductPicture.product_id,
            ProductPicture.picture_type == 'main'
        ),
    )
    option_pictures: Mapped[List["ProductPicture"]] = relationship(
        viewonly=True,
        primaryjoin=lambda: and_(
            Product.product_id == ProductPicture.product_id,
            ProductPicture.picture_type == 'option'
        ),
    )
```

Using a session context to add an example product and print the newly added attributes:

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    product = Product(
        product_name='test product',
        product_pictures=[
            ProductPicture(picture_type='main', url='p1.main.png'),
            ProductPicture(picture_type='option', url='p1.option1.png'),
            ProductPicture(picture_type='option', url='p1.option2.png'),
        ],
    )
    session.add(product)
    session.commit()
    print("product_pictures:",
        [(pic.picture_type, pic.url) for pic in product.product_pictures])
    print("main_pictures:",
        [(pic.picture_type, pic.url) for pic in product.main_pictures])
    print("option_pictures:",
        [(pic.picture_type, pic.url) for pic in product.option_pictures])
```

Should produce the following output:

```text
product_pictures: [('main', 'p1.main.png'), ('option', 'p1.option1.png'), ('option', 'p1.option2.png')]
main_pictures: [('main', 'p1.main.png')]
option_pictures: [('option', 'p1.option1.png'), ('option', 'p1.option2.png')]
```

Best tried with [the complete code example](https://gist.github.com/metatoaster/735da9a5cf82f67707bbb4bc1860a30a) as it includes all the necessary imports which were omitted from all the code examples from above.