# Is it Possible to Specify Columns through Joins in a SQLAlchemy Query?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have relationships setup in my models so SQLAlchemy knows how to join some tables together. With that, I'd like to specify all those columns up front at query time so that just one query is run. I'd think it'd be something like this:

```
q = mysql_session.query(SomeItem.col1,
                        SomeItem.some_relationship1.name,
                        SomeItem.some_relationship2.name,
                        SomeItem.col2)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with SomeItem.some_relationship1 has an attribute 'name'
```

What's the easiest way to do this? Right now, I'm just doing: `q = mysql_session.query(SomeItem)` and then looping through q, but this requires a lot of extra queries run, which is very slow and unnecessary.

Comment: Would be helpful if you actually included more details such as how the class `SomeItem` was defined, including relationships.  Please go through the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) if you want more in-depth information.  For a brief example you may refer to one of my [answers to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947160/sqlalchemy-one-to-many-relationship-how-to-filter-the-collection/24947583#24947583).

Comment: @metatoaster. Yes, I read the tutorial. If I had found this in the tutorial, I wouldn't be asking here. Why do you need SomeItem's definition? This is a general knowledge question. You just need to know that it has a working relationship through `some_relationship1` and `some_relationship2`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can do this by mentioning the joins explicitly. I'd still love it if someone answers with a more concise way of doing this, as the joins really should be implied (as in the example in the question). Anyway, this works:

```
q = mysql_session.query(SomeItem.col1,
                        SomeItem.col2,
                        SomeOtherItem1.name,
                        SomeOtherItem2.name)\
    .join(SomeOtherItem1)\
    .join(SomeOtherItem2)
```

Comment: You do need to specify the joins explicitly. (You have to do that in SQL, too, FWIW, even if you define foreign keys.)  Personally, I consider this better behavior. Joins can be very expensive so you don't want to, say, typo something and have a whole other table loaded by accident. Explicit >> implicit.

Comment: @RachelSanders what information do the joins add here? I'm still not specifying *how* to join the tables-- just that they should be joined (and it figures out how from their relationships defined in the models). Isn't this already obvious in the first formulation of the query in the example? Generally, I agree with you explicit > implicit, but here it just looks like a more verbose way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I would suspect it's because it's more general. There's more than one kind of join, and I could picture a situation where not every row had a non-null foreign key column, and by using regular joins you'd miss rows. But I'd be interested to hear if anybody has a better reason.